# Selecting most recent date when dates are stored in another table

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Working in a MySQL database, I have tables set up like this:

Table song_instances has song_id (int), meeting_instance_id (int)

The meeting_instances table has columns meeting_instance_id (int), meeting_date (datetime), meeting_id (int).

Each `meeting_id` (referencing the meetings table) might have numerous meeting_instances, and each meeting_instance might have numerous songs associated with it.

I'm trying to get a list of all songs from `song_instances` that are related to a particular meeting type (`meeting_id`)and include the date of the most recent date that the song has been used. Because the meeting_id and the meeting_date are only referenced in the meeting_instances table, I am joining that table in. But every attempt falls short.

Example:
song_instances:

```
song_id     meeting_instance_id
1           1
1           2
2           2
2           3
3           1
1           5
3           5
```

Meeting Instances:

```
meeting_instance_id      meeting_id       meeting_date
1                        4                2014-09-01
2                        4                2014-09-02
3                        2                2014-09-03
5                        4                2014-09-04
```

I want to get back:

```
song_id         lastDate
1               2014-09-04
2               2014-09-03
3               2014-09-04
```

etc.

Here is my most recent (and closest to successful) attempt.

```
SELECT si.song_id, mi.lastDate FROM song_instances si LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT MAX(meeting_date) as lastDate, meeting_id, meeting_instance_id FROM meeting_instances WHERE meeting_id = 4 GROUP BY meeting_instance_id) as mi 
    ON si.meeting_instance_id = mi.meeting_instance_id                                  
    GROUP BY si.song_id ORDER BY lastDate DESC
```

This currently gives me the date farthest in the past rather than the most recent date.
Not sure why. Any thoughts on how to improve this query?

This is a derived table from a much larger query, that is selecting song names and topics from other tables, but this is the only part of the whole query that is not working as intended.

Comment: @vijayp meeting_date is datetime

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following.

If you need most recent date for every song over all meeting instances:

```
select song_id, max(meeting_date)
from song_instances si
    join meeting_instances mi on mi.meeting_instance_id = si.meeting_instance_id
group by song_id
```

If you're interested only in particular meeting (meeting_id = 4):

```
select song_id, max(meeting_date)
from song_instances si
    join meeting_instances mi on mi.meeting_instance_id = si.meeting_instance_id
where meeting_id = 4
group by song_id
```